# Sudoers in Fedora

Tags: sudo

New user here.  I've added my user to the `wheel` group but when I try and do anything, I get a *`user not a sudoer`* error.

I uncommented the `wheel` items in `/etc/sudoers` file.  What would the next thing to check be?

Thank you.

Comment: Group membership changes take effect at next time the user logs in. Have you logged out & back in?

Comment: Sorry, yes I have logged out & back in.  I should have mentioned that.

Comment: what exactly did you uncomment? can you add it to your question? how does `/etc/group` look like?

Comment: Here is the line I changed.  Thanks for looking.

## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL

Comment: Well I've had this for a week and can't do anything other than surf the internet.  Even playing a video requires an install, which I can't do.  I'm going to blow out Fedora and go back to linux-mint.  I'll leave Fedora and it's secret commands to the serious users.